# Sum of 2 level discount

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I need to calculate sum 2 of levels discount. 1st one is item level, like 10% discount on any item. After offering this discount there is amount to receive is for example Rs.510. But shop keeper will get 500 and give him another discount Rs.10.

Now the second level discount is in main table and item wise discount is in child table. How I can calculate the sum of discount daily or monthly etc. and how I will get the following output. As when I am using `inner join` the discount in main table will be repeat for N number of items. Sum of discount on item wise is not an issue, but the invoice level is. Please help.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
Invoice No.     Date         Total Discount   Invoice Amount
--------------------------------------------------------------
INV-00001       01/01/2020        12                500
INV-00002       01/01/2020                          10000
INV-00003       01/01/2020        30                900
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: (1) Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?  (2) Please show sample data and desired results.  You mention two tables, and then show one table.  Totally unclear what it is supposed to be. One of the tables?  The results?  Something else entirely?

Comment: It seems like you might want GROUP BY ROLLUP or GROUPING SETS but you haven't posted anywhere near enough info to answer this question. Add code, sample data, actual results for that data and desired results